# Android onPause() causing Activity to crash

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, onpause

for some reason my Activity crash when I finish that specified activity. Before when I have only the onDestroy everything works fine except when i minimize the application (HOME button), the music still plays.

From what I gathered, I end up using `onDestroy()`, `onResume()` and `onPause()` to manipulate the `MediaPlayer`... but for some reason, when the activity finished, An Alert Dialog stating that `Unforunately, ProgramX has stopped.` ALTHOUGH, it continues on to the next startActivity(intent) like it should.

```
MediaPlayerAssets gls; // custom MediaPlayer Assets to fetch MediaPlayer objects
@Override 
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    gls.glbgm.pause(); // my logCat demands that the error occurs here.
    resumeToPosition = gls.glbgm.getCurrentPosition();
}


@Override
protected void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    if(gls.glbgm != null && !gls.glbgm.isPlaying())
    {
        gls.glbgm.seekTo(resumeToPosition);
        gls.glbgm.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    gls.glbgm.release();
    gls.score.release();
    gls.loser.release();
}
```

E/AndroidRuntime(23422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(23422): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity
{com.fenrirAB.request/getluckyPkg.GetLuckyGame}: java.lang.IllegalStateException

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3112)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3067)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:152)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1295)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._pause(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.pause(MediaPlayer.java:1372)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at getluckyPkg.GetLuckyGame.onPause(GetLuckyGame.java:357)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5447)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1243)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3098)

E/AndroidRuntime(23422):    ... 12 more

Comment: can you put entire stack trace here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't pause the `MediaPlayer` if it hasn't been started ([state diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)), that's why you get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`

Comment: but the background music is already prepared and started from the beginning. And the pause seem to work when the home is pressed.. its after the game is done and the Activity is finished that the error occurs... does that mean i have to create an `onStart()`

Comment: at the end of the game, does the music stop? In that case, you can't pause it either.

Comment: thanks, when you said it it suddenly hit me! i released the mp in either win-lose if statement... solved it by changing it to `pause()` THANKS A BUNCH

Answer (score 0):

What logcat says about the error? You only mention about the line error occured.

Have you ever tried this:

```
@Override 
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if(gls.glbgm != null && gls.glbgm.isPlaying())
    {
        gls.glbgm.pause(); // my logCat demands that the error occurs here.
        resumeToPosition = gls.glbgm.getCurrentPosition();
    }
}
```